# Adapting a superfish menu to what I want

Tags: theming, navigation

I am getting acquainted with Drupal 7 right now. One of the things that I have consumed a lot of time doing is understanding theming and getting the kind of Menu I want for my website.

I am using a subtheme of Bartik and have a Superfish menu (parent menu : main menu) rendering itself in the Highlighted region.

My grouch is that the menu does not render itself for the full width of the screen. The next is, I need to trigger some design changes to my menu itself which I am not sure how to.

Any leads people?

Comment: Can you give an example of 'trigger(ing) some design changes'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the menu to render to the full width of the screen make sure the containers the menu is in doesn't have any set widths, and then set the main ul to a 100% width. Superfish comes with a lot of default styles that can be hard to override. If you use the Drupal Superfish module, configure your Superfish block and set the 'Style' to none, and make sure drop-shadow is ticked off. If you don't use the module you can do this when you call Superfish with drupal_add_js (or in your init.js).